# WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm running a tiktok scrapper and I get this error. How can I fix it?

```
C:\Users\edit\Downloads\Compressed\shot\shorts\tiktokscraper\downloader.py:31: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50049/devtools/browser/85f1588d-2d26-4cbf-bd8d-a992dc20e370
[8724:8648:0711/140535.825:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:05:35.836] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter
failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edit\Downloads\Compressed\shot\shorts\tiktokscraper\downloader.py", line 98, in <module>
    download(tiktok_list)
  File "C:\Users\edit\Downloads\Compressed\shot\shorts\tiktokscraper\downloader.py", line 47, in download
    url_field = driver.find_element_by_id('url')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'
```

Comment: Here's the full code https://pastebin.com/h1m0xU00

Comment: Selenium version 4.3.0 no longer supports using `driver.find_element_by_*` try `driver.find_element(By.ID, url)` Check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 2):

Selenium version 4.3.0 no longer supports using `driver.find_element_by_*`. You should use `driver.find_element(By.ID, url)` instead.